# Python pexpect - python 2.6 - unable to print variable and > in one line

Tags: python, variables, pexpect

I am trying to concatenate string + variable + string 
picks up the variable from the file using Python

```
with open("file.txt") as fh:
for line line in fh:
d = "c:/" + xyz + ">"
print d
```

it prints c:/xyz
>
I wanted the output as "c:/xyz>". When i am trying in interactive mode it prints it fine.

Comment: > symbol comes in a new line

Comment: There's probably a `\n` in xyz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to understand the question because of the weird formatting, but in any case try using the `format` method:

```
 d = "c:/{}>".format(xyz.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: I tried this as well, i am getting the same output.

Comment: You might need to explicitly strip the `\n`. I changed the code, try again.